# Using localStorage() to save a "closed" state on modal so it doesn't show for that user again

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a pop-over modal that I am loading on my page on load, I would like to make it once it's closed to not show up again for that user. I've done similar things with `localStorage();` but for some reason can't figure out the syntax to make this work.

I tried a solution where it sets a class, but on refresh it will reload the original element, so now I am trying this idea where I change the state of of the modal to "visited". Any ideas what I could be missing to get this to work in the same way I'm hoping?

**localStorage function:**

```
$(function() {

    if (localStorage) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { 
            $('.projects-takeover').show(); 
        }
    } else { 
        $('.projects-takeover').show();
    }

    $('.projects-close').click(function() {
            $('.projects-takeover').fadeOut();
    });
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
        return false;
    });
```

Here is a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr6Lvw1q/2/)** with the code implemented as well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You javascript code is correct. Good thing you added a jsfiddle as the problem becomes very easy to identify - the modal's style is set in such a way that it is always visible. Simply change the `display` property to `nonе` in the `.projects-takeover` class and it should work. Check out the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28d4rduz/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
$(function() {
  var pt = $('.projects-takeover'); //i just hate repeating myself.
  if (localStorage) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { 
        pt.show(); 
    } else {
        pt.hide(); //this bit was missing
    }
  } else { 
    pt.show();
  }

  $('.projects-close').click(function() {
        pt.fadeOut();
  });
  localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This makes it so that the modal still appears briefly until the javascript that hides it has its chance to run. I think it would be better to make it not even show up at all if the 'visited' item is set.

Comment: @Zack,  Indeed, It was something I was going to mention, but noticed Vasil had already pointed it out.  I left my response as, it's kind of a safety net just in case visibility got message up..  IOW: No harm in doing the extra hide..